# grid View footer total in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [gridview with footer row total in the final page of the grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990661/gridview-with-footer-row-total-in-the-final-page-of-the-grid)

```
protected void inderGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            decimal rowTotal = Convert.ToDecimal
            (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "DC_No_Decimal"));
            //grdTotal = grdTotal + rowTotal;
            grdTotal += rowTotal;
        }
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
        {
            Label lbl = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblTotal");
            e.Row.Cells[3].Text = grdTotal.ToString("c");
            //lbl.Text = grdTotal.ToString("c");
        }       
    }
```

this is the code i have in row gridview rowdatabound event, Here i m getting total for every page instead of getting total of every page i want to get at the final page of the gridview footer any one Help