# gridview with footer row total in the final page of the grid

Tags: asp.net

```
protected void inderGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            decimal rowTotal = Convert.ToDecimal
            (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "DC_No_Decimal"));
            //grdTotal = grdTotal + rowTotal;
            grdTotal += rowTotal;
        }
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
        {
            Label lbl = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblTotal");
            e.Row.Cells[3].Text = grdTotal.ToString("c");
            //lbl.Text = grdTotal.ToString("c");
        }       
    }
```

from the above code i m getting total for every page in the grid view. Instead of getting total to every page i need all page total at the end of the grid view footer. Help Immediatly.
Thanks in advance

Comment: `Here i m getting total for every page instead of getting total of every page` ?

Comment: i want result at the end of the gridview page. If grid contain 20 pages means i need result at the 20th page footer by adding all the 20 pages

Comment: Asking the same question again is not allowed here.  You can add a bounty to your question to bring more attention to it.  For info about bounties, read the [faq#bounty].

Answer (score 1):

If you want the total of **ALL** pages, and for the footer to only appear on the last page, then you can't calculate the totals how you are doing.

At the moment your looping through every row on the gridview. If you are using paging the gridview won't be showing all the rows, so the total won't be correct.

Are you paging with a `PagedDataSource` or are you limiting the records returned from SQL etc? If you are using a `DataSet` and a `PagedDataSource` you'll be able to find the total from the DataSet (as this will contain all the records). Otherwise, you'll have to create a second query to calculate the total.

Then in terms of displaying the values in the footer, you'll have to add an `IF` statement to your `ItemDataBound` event to only display this if its the final page.

Answer (score 0):

Noddy but you can try one more check in the if condition.

```
if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer && inderGrid.PageCount == inderGrid.PageIndex + 1)
{
 //code here.
}
```

// Try this

```
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer && inderGrid.PageCount == inderGrid.PageIndex + 1)
    {
      for (int i=0; i< inderGrid.Rows.Count; i++)
      {
         var currentRowCellVal = Convert.ToDecimal(inderGrid.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text);
         grdTotal += currentRowCellVal;
      }

      e.Row.Cells[3].Text = grdTotal.ToString("c");

    }
```

Comment: if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer && inderGrid.PageCount == inderGrid.PageIndex + 1)
{
            Label lbl = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblTotal");
            e.Row.Cells[3].Text = grdTotal.ToString("c");
} are u telling like this

Comment: yes it the last page, but it shows the the last page total only in the footer

Comment: no i need all pages total at the end of the page, But now i m getting final page result only

Comment: it display the total at the final page, But that total is calculated from that last page only please check it

Comment: i have 22 page grid view, in that 22nd page i have value data 38, 39 & 40 in the total row it displays 117(ie., 22nd page total alone)

Comment: chk it , but i am not sure if it works, try int i = 1 if you get error as sometimes i=0 represents header of grid, depends on how you set.

Comment: alse Cells[0]  , replace 0 with your "DC_No_Decimal" cell index.

Comment: it is not working still i m getting the final page total only

Comment: The type or namespace name 'var' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
no i have the above error

Comment: Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'var' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  now i have the above error

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < inderGrid.Rows.Count; i++)
Line 269:            {
Line 270:                var currentRowCellVal = Convert.ToDecimal(inderGrid.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text);
Line 271:                grdTotal += currentRowCellVal;
Line 272:            } i have error in line number 271

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to display the record summery, please look this one about [Displaying Summary Information in the GridView's Footer](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/displaying-summary-information-in-the-gridview-s-footer-vb)

Answer (score 0):

What I do is setup the following in the code behind (This is just an example column):

```
int totalCallsTaken = 0;

public int CallsTaken(int value)
{
    totalCallsTaken += value;
    return value;
}

public int CallsTakenTotal()
{
    return totalCallsTaken;
}
```

Then in the ASPX page I put the following template field in:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Calls Taken" FooterStyle-Font-Bold="true">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%#CallsTaken(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("CallsTakenCount").ToString())).ToString("N0")%>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <%#CallsTakenTotal().ToString("N0")%>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I hope that helps, Ian.

Comment: how should i use this in my application

Answer (score 0):

Just to be certain I'm understanding, you're saying you have a grid with say 100 items, but only 25 are shown at any given time. Then you want the footer to only display the sum of those 25 items that are displayed on the page.

There's a couple of options that you can do here for this:

1) Use JavaScript to calculate the total after the page has been rendered.

2) use intelligent SQL to only return those particular rows that you're wanting to display on the grid--and then keep your grid the same

3) calculate the visible rows in your code, and only add them when you need them.  Remember, you know in the code behind which Grid.PageIndex you're on as well as how many items each page has. With this knowledge, you should be able to determine via the row index if any given datarow will be rendered to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate all records total using the actual data.

If you are doing paging at the data-sire (database) side then you have total at the data-sore side - you may use the same SP that returns a page-full of records to return the total of all records. If you are retrieving all records and doing paging at the web server side then you may use the retrieve data-source to do the totaling.

From optimization perspective, you can compute the total once and store it in the view-state.
If you wish to show the footer on the last row then you can use [ShowFooter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.showfooter.aspx) - set it to true only on the last page.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is check whether your row is in the current page and do the calculation.
For example, something like this:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    decimal rowTotal = Convert.ToDecimal
    (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "DC_No_Decimal"));
    if (e.Row.DataItemIndex >= inderGrid.PageIndex * inderGrid.PageSize
        && e.Row.DataItemIndex < inderGrid.PageIndex * inderGrid.PageSize + inderGrid.PageSize)
    grdTotal += rowTotal;
}
```

Comment: still this also displays the current page total alone

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
using System.Linq;

dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<decimal>("DC_No_Decimal")).Sum().ToString();

you can use the code like this for get sum at the footer 

gv.DataSource = dt;

gv.Columns[2].FooterText = dt.Rows.Count > 0 ? dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<decimal>("DC_No_Decimal")).Sum().ToString() : "";

gv.DataBind();
```